# Update cells of a dataframe with word occurrences given in dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dictionary of unique words from a corpus. with text occurrences as follows:

```
dict_unique_words = {'word1':3, 'word2':5, 'word3':9}
```

The word occurrences in each of three statements are as follows:

```
word_freq_statement1 = {'word2':1, 'word3' :3}
word_freq_statement2 = {'word1':3, 'word3' :1}
word_freq_statement3 = {'word2':4, 'word3' :5}
```

I want to get a dataframe as which shows the frequencies of each word in the following format:

`<table>`
`<thead>`
`<tr>`
`<th>ID</th>`
`<th>word1</th>`
`<th>word2</th>`
`<th>word3</th>`
`</tr>`
`</thead>`
`<tbody>`
`<tr>`
`<td>abc</td>`
`<td>Nan</td>`
`<td>1</td>`
`<td>3</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>xyz</td>`
`<td>3</td>`
`<td>Nan</td>`
`<td>1</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>mno</td>`
`<td>Nan</td>`
`<td>4</td>`
`<td>5</td>`
`</tr>`
`</tbody>`
`</table>`

Stuck in this for last 3 days. Please help. Heartiest thanks in advance.

Comment: Your desired output is *very* hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually what you seem to be trying to generate looks like a bag of words implementation. With that assumption in mind, I believe the "ID" that you mention in the question is the document ID.

One thing that you would need would be the `vocabulary` which is the unique words that you have in the entire dataset. Although, you mention on dictionary in the question, the output format suggests the following you will want to input multiple dictionaries and then get the output format that you are looking for.

Follow the below steps :

1. Generate the IDs for the different dictionaries like `dict_unique_words`, `word_freq_statement1`, `word_freq_statement2` etc.
2. Create a mapping dictionary for the `ID` to the dictionary object like `{1: abc}` where `abc` is a dictionary of word to frequency. Let's name this dictionary `id_to_docs`
3. Create the vocabulary of words by iterating through all the input dictionaries (which I am going to reference as `docs` from here.)
4. Now you have the IDs and the `vocab` -- values for the first row of your dataframe
5. Lets say you have a list of `IDs` and `vocab`, for each `ID` create a new row in the dataframe. Iterate over the `vocab` list and check the appropriate value for the word in the vocab list by looking up the occurrence of the word in the document. `doc` using `id_to_docs`. If the vocab value does not exist then you set it to NaN.

Creating the xmlesque form of dataframe is down to just formatting the string that comes out of step 5.

Comment: Thank you so much Naveen.I am trying to implement your steps.